# how to remove form,formitems in flex

Tags: apache-flex, forms

in my application im using a form...

```
<mx:Form x="10" y="22"  id="f1" >
    <mx:FormItem label="Location Code" id="labandtext">
        <mx:TextInput id="locCodeTxt" editable="false"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

for removing the form im using the following:

```
f1.removeAllChildren();
```

If i want to get the removedChildren (FormItems,TextInput)...how can i get back those childrens(FormItems,TextInput)...
kindly give some suggestions..Thankxxx..:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not removing them from display list. You can just hide them:

```
f1.visible = false;
f1.includeInLayout = false;
```

Then, set these properties to true, when you need the Form.

Comment: i used the above one... then when i need the form i set the properties as true. but when i use f1.visible = false; f1.includeInLayout = false; the label and textbox in the form is always visible in true state....what shall i do for tat??

Comment: @ConquistadorAravinth sorry, I'm not sure, I've got the idea. Do you use anything else in your form besides textinput? If it is so and you need to hide only textinput, then use `labandtext.visible = false; labandtext.includeInLayout = false;`

Comment: yeah..thankx man...it works perfect....yeah have to include labandtext.visible = false; labandtext.includeInLayout = false;...Good one Davydik....Thanks a Lot Man!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store them in an Array.

Before you remove you can say.

```
var previousChildren:Array = f1.getChildren();
f1.removeAllChildren()
```

;

if you want to re-add them you can use:

```
for each(var element:FormItem in previousChildren){
    f1.addElement(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `states`, to handle different aspects of you forms, and avoid the repeated remove - add instructions.

- If you are using **Flex3** (mx,
  halo), then [this article](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=using_states_3.html) will
  help you understanding the basics.
- For **Flex4** you should refer to
  [this article](http://www.artima.com/articles/flex_4_states.html).

This would be the best way to handle your different layout behaviors